# How to disable remote debugging in VS2008 C#.NET Windows app

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am trying to debug a C#.NET Windows application that I'm developing to be a client for a third-party web service. I do not want to do any remote debugging with the web service, but my code fails at the line that calls the web service. I get this error:

"Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine "machine.name" failed. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. This may be because the remote computer does not exist or a firewall may be preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see help for assistance."

I do not want to step into or have the debugger connect to the remote computer. I just want to debug my local code and nothing else. I can find no information anywhere that would tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you manually have to set it (through code) in your application.

[How do you find what debug switches are available? Or given a switch find out what is being disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334/how-do-you-find-what-debug-switches-are-available-or-given-a-switch-find-out-wha/33683#33683)